# Import Python files from /

Tags: python, docker

When my Python files are located in the file system's root folder `/`, and `/` is in `PYTHONPATH`, can I import those files using their package name? That is, can I assign the files located in `/` to a package? For example, using the `__init__.py` file?

This use case arises when I dockerize my Python project, and want to have `/` as the root folder of the source tree.

Comment: Are you saying you have a `__init__.py` in `/`, and want to use the root as a package? Or just that you have packages as directories directly under `/` that have their own `__init__.py`? The latter should just work just by adding `/` to `PYTHONPATH`; the former shouldn't work because it's wrong (you should never have a package directory on your `sys.path`).

Comment: Meanwhile, instead of asking whether it would work, why not just try it and see what happens? If there are any surprises and you can't figure out why it is/isn't working, then you have a useful question to ask, but if it just works as expected, there is no question.

Comment: Putting source in `/` doesn’t seem like a great idea, though… there’s a bunch of other stuff in there, no?

Comment: @abarnert, I can't even try it out as I don't know by which package name to refer to the files in the root folder. That's exactly my question. Ry, it's for a docker image, so there is nothing else there.

Comment: @abarnert, yes, I want to use root as a package.

Comment: OK, you can't make `/` itself into a package, because it doesn't have a parent directory to add to `sys.path`. You can put a package directly under `/`, which is what I thought you were asking, by adding `/` to the path. Or you can drop flat modules that aren't part of a package directly into `/`, by doing the same thing. But `/` can't be a package.

Comment: You might be able to get away with putting the main script and `__init__.py` both in `/` and using only relative imports from `.` if you don't need to refer to the package itself. But, even if it works, it's not legal to have a package's directory on the path, and it causes all kinds of headaches.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you want to formulate that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.